# Adding 'All' option in selectizejs using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, selectize.js

Im trying to use selectizejs with angularjs, following the plunker link im able to implement the selectbox, but im unable to add an option like "All countries" which will be selected by default. Please help me to solve this.

Scope: list of posts by country, Default All countries will be given, on user selection, posts by country will be shown and when user selects "All countries" need to show all posts. (In Plunker third option im using in my web "Selectize theme")

Comment: sorry missed the plunker link its http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

Comment: If selectizejs doesn't work for you, I use this directive and it works great. Comes with the select all feature already (Also doesn't use jQuery which is a bonus): http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

Comment: thanks@Ronnie but i need the autocomplete as it is in selectize so i want to use selectize only by adding 'All' option in it, Anyway thanks for suggestion

Comment: The one I posted has autocomplete as well